# Line "--" appearing on locating text from web page through selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This is the image i want to locate its web element and elements which i want to locate are text return after QTY.(3) , which is not locating . I have used different methods to locate but it is not getting done then i tried to get the html of whole page then the it come like the the thing written in span is not visible there , in place of the text written inside span there appears a --- line.How I can locate this elements as the things is dynamic means the elements are based on the user portfolio of stocks i.e. it can be 1,2,3 or xyz.

[image: 1]

Comment: Page is behind a login, cannot check it. Most likely the data in that page is being loaded via an XHR call, so it's not available right on page load, you needd to wait for it. Try using WebDriverWait/ expected_conditions. Or better, try scraping ddirectly that source API, with requests.

Comment: okay , thanks i will try your approach and get back to you

Comment: yes it appears after login and pressing a button transferring to a different page thaen these elements  appear